# Reduce loop to a vector form

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to reduce this loop to a vector form without any loops?

```
data = randn(1000,1);
center1 = [1,2,3];
for i=1:size(data,1)
    A(i,(i-1)*3+1:i*3) = 2*(data(i,:)-center1);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SEU:

I copied your code and ran it using `A=[]` just to determine the array size. It came out to be `1000 X 3000`. The array `A` on my end worked out to be some kind of sparse tridiagonal matrix with offsets.

Anyhow, with that in mind, I was able to formulate the linear index vectorizations for those bands (see `vec1`, `vec2`, and `vec3` below). These might be difficult to understand if one is accustomed to double-index notation (AKA rows and columns). Below the code I explain some of the intuition behind linear index vectorizations.

```
N = 1000; %Number of random points to generate.
A = zeros(N,3*N); %The ensuing matrix has these dimensions.
data = randn(N,1); %random point generation.
center1 = [1,2,3]; %"Offsets..." ???
vec1 = 1:3*N+1:3*N^2 - 2*N; %Vectorization for the first band. (left-most)
vec2 = N+1:3*N+1:3*N^2 - N; %Vectorization for the second band. (middle)
vec3 = 2*N+1:3*N+1:3*N^2; %Vectorization for the third band. (right-most)
A([vec1,vec2,vec3]) = 2*[(data-center1(1)),...
    (data-center1(2)),...
    (data-center1(3))]; %Assignment of values.
```

In linear indexing, each element has its position in the array denoted by a single number. For example, the top left corner of an array has a linear index of `1`, the bottom left corner has a linear index of `N`, where `N` is the number of rows in the array. The top right corner of an array has a linear index of `1+N*(C-1)`, where `C` is the number of columns. In the above example `C = 3*N` Finally, the bottom right corner has a linear index of `N*C`. For a given array element, one references the elements to the right and left of it by adding `N` or subtracting `N` respectively. Similarly, to do so with the vertical adjacent elements above and below some element, one subtracts `1` and adds `1` respectively. To move in the main diagonal direction, add or subtract `N+1`. To move in the counter diagonal direction, add or subtract `N-1`. Hopefully, this illustrates how these vectorizations work.